# What refer "this" to in backbone's listenTo()

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I wrote some code following...

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
...
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(collection, 'add', this.addOne)
  },
  addOne : function (item) {
   this // 'this' here refers... what?
})
```

I read the [guide](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/)
In this guide, "this" on listenTo refers "listener", but i tested the code above, "this" may be the view itself

In "events and views" section,
"If the event is bound using listenTo() then within the callback this refers to the listener."

Comment: Did you try `console.log(this)` and see what it says?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar console.log says "the view"

Comment: LoL. Wow? Seriously? So then it could be referring to [`this`](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-view).

Comment: @PraveenKumar this refers to it's view when event is bound to view using event hash(events property). my question is "this refers to it's view when using listenTo() method too.. TT

Comment: You are looking for this: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet is from documentation 
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

```
listenToobject.listenTo(other, event, callback)
```

Tell an object to listen to a particular event on an other object. The advantage of using this form, instead of other.on(event, callback, object), is that listenTo allows the object to keep track of the events, and they can be removed all at once later on. The callback will always be called with object as context.

```
view.listenTo(model, 'change', view.render);
```

It very well explains `this` refers to the object `listenTo` is called with. 
For ex: `object.listenTo(...)` will have object as context i.e `this` will be the object in callback.

Code snippet in the above question essentially calls listenTo on view object, and hence `this` is actually view

Comment: @fasdgoc Accept the answer, if its satisfactory :)